# Dynamic Height not working with pinned columns using MUI's DataGridPro

Tags: material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

I've got a material-ui DataGridPro with a name and numerical data in each row. I need to pin the name column to the left, but the dynamic row height no longer works when the column is pinned. The name cell overflows, and causes all the name cells to be offset from their row.

[Here is a screen shot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQcmK.png)

Here are the properties I'm using:

```
<DataGridPro
  density="compact"
  rows={rows}
  columns={columns}
  initialState={{
    pinnedColumns: { left: ['name'] },
  }}
  getRowHeight={() => 'auto'}
/>
```

I've already worked through the code presented by MUI about dynamic row height with rows that change their content after initial calculation: https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/column-pinning/#usage-with-dynamic-row-height

This did not solve the problem. It appears the error in row height calculation happen on the first render, so running `apiRef.current.resetRowHeights()` doesn't fix the problem.